# Looping through strings and replacing adjoining characters

Tags: python

I need to know how to switch 2 characters in a string. For example, I have:

```
###################################
####         ######################
####  ###        ###           ####
####  ###        ###           ####
####  ###                      ####
o     ###        ##################
###################################
```

I want this to be like moving throughout the “House” so I have a program that receives an input from the user using WASD keys. When pressing R, the ‘o’ will move towards the right, when pressing ‘W’ it will go up, etc.
Since I want to do that, I would have to switch the ‘o’ with the space to the right, or the ‘o’ with the space on top. Is there a easy, efficient way of doing this? I searched the web and I found some results related but since I’m a beginner I don’t really understand because they were using complicated functions and string slicing. Could somebody give me some code to do this?

I have tried things like:

```
if input.lower() == ‘w’:
 House = ‘’’

###################################
####         ######################
####  ###        ###           ####
####  ###        ###           ####
####  ###                      ####
 o    ###        ##################
###################################

’’’
```

But it would take me way too long to manually do every single little change in position so can someone make any answer with code in how to do this?

Comment: This site is not a coding service. If you want someone coding something for you, you should place a job offer. ;)

Comment: share what you wrote so far

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you are working with a map thats printed in the terminal

You should think of the house as a 2 dimensional array where the 0s are free space and the 1s are the wall (or the other way around, thats just preference).
That way when you are printing the map you are just printing an empty space, a # or the players marker:

```
Map = 
[
  [0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1],
  [1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0],
  ....
]
```

The position of the player is a position in that array:

```
Player = [2,5] ## Third Row Sixth Column
```

Based on that you can calculate where the player can move:

```
Up: [1,5]
Down: [3,5]
Left: [2,4]
Right: [2,6]
```

Once the player did his move, print the map again with something that could look like this:

```
def PrintMap(Map, Player = [0,0]):
for i in Map
    Row = ''
    for j in i:
        if [i, j] == Player:
            Row = Row + 'o'
        elif j == 0:
            Row = Row + ' '
        else:
            Row = Row + '#'  
    print(Row)
```